# ogr2ogr import fails with "ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex"

Tags: postgresql, geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to import a large (8.8GB) GeoJSON file to a Postgres 9.6 database with the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -nln final_diffs PG:"host=localhost dbname=inspire user=me" diffs.geojson
```

But I get lots of warnings like this:

```
ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex
ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex
More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.
```

And the process runs without errors, but at the end, nothing has been imported into the Postgres database.

Any ideas? I've not seen this warning before, and the only online reference I can find is in the [GDAL source code](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson/ogrgeojsonreader.cpp).

All I get from `ogrinfo` is the above warnings, then:

```
Layer name: diffs
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 0
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error comes from the GDAL GeoJSON driver. The source code is in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson/ogrgeojsonreader.cpp.

The max value is defined on line 50

```
const size_t MAX_OBJECT_SIZE = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
```

There are tooComplex checks in many places and that throws the errot that you saw

```
void OGRGeoJSONReaderStreamingParser::TooComplex()
{
    if( !ExceptionOccurred() )
        Exception("GeoJSON object too complex");
}
```

I do not know really what to do but I can suggest

- Send a link of your data to gdal-dev mailing list and ask them to evaluate if that GeoJSON dataset is unreasonable or if the 200 * 1024 * 1024 limit should be raised again. It has already been doubled a few months ago because of this ticket https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/807.
- Raise the value yourself; it would require to compile GDAL from the sources
- Write a mail to the data provider and ask them to analyze if they could make the offending geometry smaller or use some other format, perhaps GeoPackage.

Answer (score 6):

If you have GDAL >= 3.02, then you can set environment variable *OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE* (as mentioned [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#configuration-options)) and run *ogr2ogr*, for example:

- Windows: `SET OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE=500MB`
- Linux: `export OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE=500MB`

Default value of *OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE* is 200MB.

Answer (score 4):

[Wilhelm Berg](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12821/wilhelm-berg) and I ran into this problem recently, and he found that using [tippecanoe-json-tool](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#tippecanoe-json-tool) to convert the large geojson to a line-delimited geojson made it digestible for `ogr2ogr`:

```
tippecanoe-json-tool my_large_file.geojson > my_large_file.ldjson
```

`ogr2ogr` can then read the .ldjson file using the new [GeoJSONSeq driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojsonseq.html), which should prevent OOM errors:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG my_large_file.gpkg my_large_file.ldjson
```

NB: This has been tested on a 1.5 GB geojson - haven't tried on anything as large as the OP's 8.8 GB file.

Comment: Hmm. That seemed to just turn the file into nonsense geometry for me :/ I guess it doesnt know what to do with MultiPolygons?

Comment: Hmm I've used it with MultiPolygons before @Shayne. Could you share an MWE?

Comment: Boss won't let me. I worked around my problem by exporting shape files out of QGIS (These where geojson files exported from QGIS hooking up to a ArcGIS/Esri type server, a lot of these layers are many gigs in size.)

Comment: Sounds good. If you're ever able to share a multipolygon that tippecanoe can't handle, let me know!